# return value of QTcpSocket::write(QByteArray& buf);

Tags: qt, sockets

Dose this function always return buf.size() or -1?
if not ,dose it mean I need recall the function to write the left data not be written?

for example, if I have a 100 bytes of QByteBuffer.
when I call "tcpSocket.write(buf_100_bytes)" , is it possible that I get 60 or something else?

Additionally, dose this function return immediately?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld:Thanks for your warn,that's not my real intention. I will pay attention. I have tried vote or accept to others before, but the site warned me that I havn't enough priviledget, so I think only the one who answered enough questions can vote..may be i need read the faq of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with POSIX write(), the QIODevice::write() returns the number of bytes written. That can be any number between 0 and the buffer size. Also, in case of an error, it might return a negative number, which you should check for separately.
QIODevice::write() does not block for sockets (they are set to non-blocking mode), the bytes are just added to a buffer and written later.
To get a notification when bytes are written, you can connect to the bytesWritten(qint64) signal. To block until the bytes are actually written, you can use waitForBytesWritten() (usually not a good idea in the main/UI thread).

Comment: +1 one to Frank's post. I'd just add that POSIX is *nix systems API, but I'm sure the algorithm for say Windows is similar

Comment: Thanks very much!   If it's not block for sockets, dose it mean that  "write(something); something=NULL;" is not safe? because when the system actually want write the data, but the data is set NULL...

Comment: Ok,I think I get it, my last comment is stupid:),it's safe if I do so, because the system will deep copy the data to the socket buffer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I quote Qt documentation:

> Writes at most maxSize bytes of data from data to the device. Returns the number of bytes that were actually written, or -1 if an error occurred.

It means, it will return the number of bytes written or -1 in case of an error. You can get error by calling error() method or connection to error() signal.