# Qt QIODevice::write / QTcpSocket::write and bytes written

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

We are quite confused about the behavior of `QIODevice::write` in general and the `QTcpSocket` implementation specifically. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660253/return-value-of-qtcpsocketwriteqbytearray-buf) already, but the answer is not really satisfactory. The main confusion stems from the there mentioned `bytesWritten` signal respectively the `waitForBytesWritten` method. Those two seem to indicate the bytes that were written from the buffer employed by the `QIODevice` to the actual underlying device (there must be such buffer, otherwise the method would not make much sense). The question then is though, if the number returned by `QIODevice::write` corresponds with this number, or if in that case it indicates the number of bytes that were *stored* in the *internal buffer*, not the bytes written to the *underlying device*. If the number returned would indicate the bytes written to the internal buffer, we would need to employ a pattern like the following to ensure all our data is written:

```
void writeAll(QIODevice& device, const QByteArray& data) {
   int written = 0;
   do {
     written = device.write(data.constData() + written, data.size() - written);
   } while(written < data.size());
}
```

However, this will insert duplicate data if the return value of `QIODevice::write` corresponds with the meaning of the `bytesWritten` signal. The documentation is very confusing about this, as in both methods the word *device* is used, even though it seems logical and the general understanding, that one actually indicates written to buffer, and not device.

So to summarize, the question is: Is the number returned bye `QIODevice::write` the number of bytes written to the underlying device, and hence its save to call `QIODevice::write` *without* checking the returned number of bytes, as everything is stored in the internal buffer. Or does it indicate how much bytes it could store internally and a pattern like the above `writeAll` has to be employed to safely write all data to the device?

(UPDATE: Looking at the source, the `QTcpSocket::write` implementation actually will never return less bytes than one wanted to write, so the `writeAll` above is not needed. However, that is specific to the socket and this Qt version, the documentation is still confusing...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That previous question answers your question, as does the [`QIODevice::write(const char * data, qint64 maxSize)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html#write) documentation:

> Writes **at most** maxSize bytes of data from data to the device. Returns the number of bytes that were actually written, or -1 if an error occurred.

This can (and will in real life) return less than what you requested, and it's up to you to call `write` again with the remainder.

As for [`waitForBytesWritten`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html#waitForBytesWritten):

> **For buffered devices**, this function waits until a payload of buffered written data has been written to the device...

It applies only to buffered devices. Not all devices are buffered. If they are, and you wrote less than what the buffer can hold, `write` can return successfully before the device has finished sending all the data.

Devices are not necessarily buffered.

Comment: How does the `waitForBytesWritten` fit into that then? The word device seems to be overloaded in the documentation, as it refers to an internal buffer for write, but must mean to the actual underlying device for `waitForBytesWritten`. If not, that method would not make any sense at all, is I got the information already from write, so there has to be an internal buffer Qt uses. And either the return value of `write` returns to that buffer (as you say) or also to the underlying device (which is the term used in the documentation). Hence its very unclear to me.

Comment: Edited. A write to a device is a write to the device, regardless of whether it's buffered.

Comment: Thx, I wasn't fully aware of the notion of buffered and unbuffered devices. However, it's still very confusing that they would use 'device' in `QIODevice::write` meaning the internal buffer or the actual device whereas it's specifically meaning the actual underlying device for the `waitForBytesWritten` method. Also the fact that, according to crysm's answer, QTcpSocket is apparently buffered and in the current implementation there is no scenario where write files, it might actually still be that the notion of the write is the same as the one in `waitForBytesWritten`.

Answer (score 5):

`QTcpSocket` is a buffered `QAbstractSocket`. An internal buffer is allocated inside `QAbstractSocket`, and data is copied in that buffer. The return value of write is the size of the data passed to `write()`.

`waitForBytesWritten` waits until the data in the internal buffer of `QAbstractSocket` is written to the native socket.